# Get calculated CSS-property defined with percentage (max-width and max-height)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a safe approach to get the calculated value of CSS-properties which are not "active" at the moment like `min-width`, `min-height`, `max-width`, `max-height` and so on.

My CSS-code whould be like this:

```
.element {
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 60%;
}
```

jQuery returns the raw value if I use this:

```
$('.element').css('max-width'); // returns "60%"
```

The funny thing is that I get the correct px-result with other units:

```
max-width: 60em; // returns "960px"
max-width: 60rem; // returns "960px"
max-width: 60vh; // returns "396px"
max-width: 60vmax; // returns "1132px"
max-width: 60pt; // returns "80px"
```

A simple solution would be just to calculate it myself:

```
function calculatePixelFromPercentage(percentage, size) {
   return parseFloat(size * (parseFloat(percentage) / 100));
}

calculatePixelFromPercentage($('.element').css('max-width'), $('.element').parent().innerWidth());
```

The problem is that the **result could be wrong depending on positioning**: absolute-positioned elements should include padding, relative-positioned ones should exclude padding. And if the parent of the absolute-positioned one is not relative, the result is different again. So I wonder if there is a safe solution which pays attention to this CSS-peculiarities.

And why didn't jQuery's `css`-function calculate this? The specification (http://api.jquery.com/css/) tells me it should be calculated.

Do you know any solutions?